# Spring Batch - Read from FlatFile write Valid into Database and Invalid into FlatFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am new to *Spring Batch*, and trying to read data from *FlatFile* and writing the valid record into the database and invalid record into *cvs* file.
I used `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` for writing into multiple *FlatFile*. It was working fine, but the same was not working while trying to write in DB and *FlatFile* at the same time. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Please consider adding the code and pin pointing the exact issue to enable people help you.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` for that use case, instead, it is more natural to use a [SkipListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#skipListener) for invalid data.

In your example, you can use a regular item writer to write valid data to the database, and register a skip listener that would write invalid items to a file.

You can implement the skip logic in an item processor for example. This processor would check if the current item is valid: It it is valid, let it go to the writer, otherwise throw a skippable exception.

Hope this helps.